# ZFS. Unmount duplicated entries

Tags: unix, freebsd, zfs

After some unsuccessful experiments with zfs snapshots I see following output for 'zfs list':

```
$ zfs list
NAME                                    USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank                                   1.48T  2.64T  25.4K  none
tank/home                              92.6K  2.64T  92.6K  legacy
tank/jails                             1.46T  2.64T  41.1K  legacy
tank/jails/jail05                      18.3G  2.64T  17.7G  /jails/jail05
tank/jails/jail06                      18.3G  2.64T  17.7G  /jails/jail06
tank/jails/somefldr                    18.3G  2.64T  17.7G  /jails/jail06
```

Now there are two mountpoints with the same name (**/jails/jail06**) pointing to different zfs directories. 
The zfs unmount command doesn't work.

```
$ sudo zfs unmount /jails/jail06
cannot unmount '/jails/jail06': not a mountpoint
```

Looking for any advice to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Upd:

```
zfs mount
```

displays no **/jails/jail06** mounted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mount` to see whether the filesystem is actually mounted. Just because it has a given mountpoint doesn't mean it's mounted.

It looks like you have set the mountpoint for the zfs filesystems and they are not mounted.

Comment: yep, I've just figured out that fs wasn't mounted.

Answer (score 3):

You can unmount by name instead of mountpoint:

```
zfs unmount tank/jails/jail06
```

You can change mountpoint for particular dataset:

```
zfs set mountpoint=/jails/somefldr tank/jails/somefldr
```

Also "zfs list" shows list of all datasets (mounted and unmounted)

Comment: thanks for this point. actually my fsystems wasn't mounted, so I simply changed mountpoint and then did 'zfs mount'